# Optimal series expansion for "invertability"

Tags: power-series, inverse

**Motivation:**

Often when dealing with physical phenomena, deviations from the model must be considered, so a variable, say $x\in[0,1]$ will be replaced by a power series expansion:
$$x'\ \to \ x(1+k x^2 + \ldots), \quad |k|\ll1$$ 
This can be seen for instance in the distortion corrections for lens, or in the equation for the force applied by a spring.

A problem arises when we want to invert this equation - the inverse of the cubic function $y = x(1+kx^2)$ is a mess, and adding higher terms makes an analytic solution for the inverse impossible.

**Here's the question:**

Do there exist **non power** series expansions that lead to simpler inversion formula? Specifically, I'm looking for a sequence of non-power functions $f_n(x)$, that when given a finite series such as:
$$y(x) = x\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_i f_i(x)\right)$$
Then we should also be able to expand the inverse of $y$ in a finite number of these functions $f_n$:
$$y^{-1}(x) = x\left(\sum_{i=0}^m b_i f_i(x)\right)$$

So, do such $f_n$ exist? I'm looking for non trivial $f_n$, preferably that can be used to approximate a wide variety of smooth functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following

$$
x = y - k x^3 = y - k(y- k x^3)^3  = y - ky ^3 - 3 k^2 y^2 x^3 + 3 k^3 y x^6 - k^4 x^9
$$
You can extend this to any accuracy you want.

By contraction mapping results, you can estimate the error.

Note that the expansion is a contraction map of $|3 k x^2| <1$ and $\rho=|3 k x^2| is useful in bounding the error.

Based on the edit provided by OP

To keep the symbols straight, I will 
write
$$x(y) = y\left(\sum_{i=0}^m b_i f_i(y)\right)$$

Note that this can never be exact. However to the accuracy in the original equation:

$$ y = x + k x^3$$ 
we have
$$ x = y - k x^3$$

For this inversion to work in general we need
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \sum_{i=0}^m a_i f_i(x) \neq 0$$

Comment: Thank you - although that's not quite what I meant - I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Still not a finite inversion :)

Comment: I am sure that there is some theorem that says that finite inversion is not possible unless $f_i$ are constants (not a very interesting case).

Comment: Unless it's *not* a power series..

Comment: I will have to think about it. Something tells me that it is not possible.